# Looking for program to export data from MS SQL database

Tags: sql

I need to export some tables in a MS SQL database.

The ASP.NET Enterprise Manager provided by the host doesn't offer much functionality. Can someone recommend a good program for doing this?

I only have FTP and Control Panel access to the account.

I tried phpMSAdmin but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which version you are (your host is) running.  Also, are you looking for a "permanent" fix, as "I'm migrating to a new host", or just "I need to regularly export my {insert app here} data to another app"?

Probably the simplest answer is to write it yourself: any language that can query the database could be used to write it to anywhere else (another database, CSV, HTML, etc) ...

Does your FTP access let you get to the actual files (usually `database_name.mdf` and `database_name.ldf`)?  If so, you could (if the admin console lets you) detach the database, copy the files, and attach them to a local instance.  A related tactic would be to run a backup, bring the backup files over, and restore them to a local instance.